# Bash script with wildcards

Tags: bash

here's an example of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /upper/folder.test*/subfolder
ls
```

The folder.test folder s actually named something like "folder.test13kwekrjk1234jk3", and it's completely random, so I want to use a wild card. The "Upper" folder is in root, where I want it and the CD command works outside the script (and I'm executing it in the root directory, just like the script)

However, when I execute (using ./) it gives me:

"- No such file or directory] cd:/upper/folder.test*/subfolder"

What gives? It works outside of the script but it won't work inside the script? Should I be doing this a different way inside the script?

Comment: I can't get this to fail like you have it, but also note that the script you have will only `ls` the first occurrence but not the rest. Something like `ls /upper/folder.test*/subfolder` would work, however. Also, what OS or version of bash are you using?

Comment: It works on my version of bash. Do you have more than one directory that match the pattern?

Comment: Isn't this a case of confusing wildcards with filename *globbing* ? Something like `ls /upper/folder.test*/subfolder` would work because of shell expansion of the asterisk, but expansion in a `cd` command wouldn't make sense. You can only `cd` to *one* folder

Comment: Which bash version are you using? Does `shopt` give some other output in the script than outside?

Comment: Post the smallest possible script that fails, not an "example" of your script. Also, post the *exact* error message. Do not put quotes around it, and ensure SO formatting does not change what is displayed. That error message you gave looks wrong with the surrounding quotes, leading -, unmatched ] and : between `cd` and the path.

Comment: The fact that the error message shows the * means that there was no valid expansion - the shell will simply leave the string in place with the * if it cannot expand it. So maybe you don't have a directory with a matching name, at the point the cd runs.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this instead because wildcards are literally wildcards, their behavior is hard to predict and less reliable.

```
FOLDER=$(ls -1 /upper/folder.test*/subfolder | head -n1);
cd "$FOLDER"
ls
```

Comment: Just a hint, the `-1` is redundant, whenever `ls`s standard out is not a terminal, it sets formatting to single column, to colors.

Comment: One more note, if you're trying to detect a directory path with this you will also need the `-d` flag to `ls`. At least in Centos 5.x, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a related problem when I tried to cd to my home directory using "~" in a bash script.

This code worked in the terminal, but not in my script:

```
cd ~/Documents/important_folder*
```

However, the below code worked fine in the script:

```
cd /home/my_username/Documents/important_folder*
```